# Detecting total RAM change in Windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Is there a callback in Windows which will notify my application if the total amount of System RAM has changed?

Comment: Are you talking about hot-swappable RAM?

Comment: Yeah, hot adding memory or configuring memory on a virtual machine while it is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do this via WMI, if you can pick up [_InstanceCreationEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394649%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [_InstanceDeletionEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394650%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on class [Win32_PhysicalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347%28VS.85%29.aspx).

There is sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (WMI is a bear to use in C or C++, sorry - C# would be easier).  Just make the query you listen on use `Win32_PhysicalMemory` rather than `Win32_Process` here:

```
hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
    _bstr_t("WQL"), 
    _bstr_t("SELECT * " 
        "FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 "
        "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"), 
    WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS, 
    NULL, 
    pStubSink);
```

You'd also need a second call like this for `__InstanceDeletionEvent` detection.

Comment: I don't believe Windows allows giving up memory once added.